# VBA Excel wait for shell with ansys to finish

Tags: shell, vba, excel

I have written a macro to run Ansys and if Ansys is closed the macro should run on.

My Problem here is that I run Ansys with some scripts so the code for running it is

```
retval = shell("C:\...\runwb2 -X -R C:\...\Script.py -F C:\...\Workbenchproject.wbpj", vbNormalFocus)
```

This works perfectly fine until I want to wait for it to finish

Using

```
Dim wsh As Object  
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
cmd = "C:\...\runwb2 -X -R C:\...\Script.py -F C:\...\Workbenchproject.wbpj"  
retval = wsh.Run(cmd, 1,True)
```

gives me a runtime error -2147024894 (0x80070002)

If it is possible I don't want to use something big like ShellAndWait I found earlier, just something simple

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have found my problem.
The path to run ANSYS Workbench was the default installation path with the folder "ANSYS Inc", the space is not a problem if I use shell() but if I use the WScript.Shell the space produces the runtime error. I had to change the Path so there is no more space and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

To pause for a five seconds....

```
'// Start Code Snippet

Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 5)

'// End Code Snippet
```

However, per your code you are setting WaitOnReturn to TRUE, which SHOULD be doing what you want it to do... so I don't know why you'd be getting an error. let me know if this helps.. thanks, Brian